# Nginx как правильно преобразовать .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Имеется .htacces такого содержания

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^post_([0-9]+) ?mode=post&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^feed_([0-9]+)_(.+) ?mode=feed&id=$1&token=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^feed_([0-9]+) ?mode=feed&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^flow_([0-9]+)_(.+) ?mode=flow&id=$1&token=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^flow_([0-9]+) ?mode=flow&id=$1 [L]
```

Преобразую его в такой конфиг

```
location /feed_ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location /flow_ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;  
}

location /post_ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;  
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/feed_([0-9]+)_(.+) /?mode=feed&id=$1&token=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/feed_([0-9]+) /?mode=feed&id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/flow_([0-9]+)_(.+) /?mode=flow&id=$1&token=$2 last;   
    rewrite ^/flow_([0-9]+) /?mode=flow&id=$1 last; 
    rewrite ^/post_([0-9]+) /?mode=post&id=$1 last;
}
```

Вроде все работает, но есть у меня подозрения что я что то делаю не так. И возможно ли в даном случае избавится о rewrite и использовать return?

Весь конфиг

```
server {
listen 443 ssl default;
server_name name;

charset utf-8;

rewrite_log on;
access_log /var/log/nginx/time.log time_log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/simplicator.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/simplicator.error.log;

keepalive_timeout   60;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/private.key;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers  "RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=604800';

root /path/to/root;


location / {

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

}

location /feed_ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location /flow_ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;  
}

location /post_ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;  
}

location @rewrite {
    #return 503;
    rewrite ^/feed_([0-9]+)_(.+) /?mode=feed&id=$1&token=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/feed_([0-9]+) /?mode=feed&id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/flow_([0-9]+)_(.+) /?mode=flow&id=$1&token=$2 last;   
    rewrite ^/flow_([0-9]+) /?mode=flow&id=$1 last; 
    rewrite ^/post_([0-9]+) /?mode=post&id=$1 last;
}

location ~ /\. {
 deny all;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос - вот вы сделали `rewrite` на корень - а чем дальше вы обрабатываете корень? Кстати, зачем вы делаете `try_files`? У вас может где-то лежать файл, называемый `/post_1234`? Не верю :)

Возможно, стоило бы вообще убрать все, что вы понаписали - и напрямую запускать тот обработчик, который был повешен в корень, для нужных URL. Возможно, получится еще и корневой обработчик убрать - это будет еще полезнее для безопасности.

---

Вижу, вы добавили конфиг целиком. Интересно, у вас на сайте все запросы должны проходить через `index.php` - или некоторые могут проходить "мимо"? Во втором случае конфиг довольно адекватный. А в первом - в нем много лишнего.

Вам не надо обрабатывать все файлы `.php` - вам надо обрабатывать один из них. Настройте `fastcgi_pass` непосредственно для корня, без директив `index` или `try_files`. Внутри - отдельные `location` для маршрутов. Для отдачи статики также настройте отдельные `location`, снаружи корня.

Comment: Добавил конфиг целиком, особенно интресно со стороны правильности написания конфига под nginx. Навеянно рекомендациями Игроя Сысоева на hl++. Вот только как применять на практике эти советы не всегда понятно...